# Transfer Google In-App Billing subscription from one app to other

Tags: android, in-app-billing

We are discontinuing our existing app and launching new app, and want to transfer all current Google Android in-app billing subscribers to new app. any idea if it is even possible?

Comment: That's something I've also considered some time ago. It is not possible to do (unless it was not by the time I was trying to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You may use old app service as proxy to get subscriptions. So old subscribers have to use two apps. I guess the service has to share the same process for security issues.